# (Elasticsearch.Net 7 - NEST 7) Invalid NEST response built from a successful (404) low level call on PUT

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using Elasticsearch version 7.7 and NEST 7.7

```
  <PackageReference Include="Elasticsearch.Net" Version="7.7.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="NEST" Version="7.7.0" />
```

This is my code to create the index

```
    var connectionPool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(elasticUrl));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
   .BasicAuthentication(elasticUsername, elasticPassword)
   .DeadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300))
   .DisableDirectStreaming()
   .DefaultIndex("demo_index");

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var response = client.Indices.Create("eagle-Dev-products",
            index => index.Map<ElasticSimpleProduct>(
                x => x.AutoMap()
            ));

    return response.DebugInformation;
```

This is my index model

```
  [ElasticsearchType(RelationName = "searchproduct")]
    public class ElasticSimpleProduct
    {
        [Number(DocValues = false, IgnoreMalformed = true, Coerce = true)]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Keyword]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [Text]
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }

        [Text]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Text]
        public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }

        [Text]
        public string MetaDescription { get; set; }

        [Text]
        public string MetaTitle { get; set; }

        [Text]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [Text]
        public string FullDescription { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

But I'm getting this error

```
    "Invalid NEST response built from a successful (404) low level call on PUT: /eagle-Dev-products\r
\n# Audit trail of this API call:\r
     \n - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: https://eagle-demo.kb.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243/ Took: 00:00:13.8974690\r
\n# Request:\r
    n{\"mappings\":{\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"coerce\":true,\"ignore_malformed\":true,\"doc_values\":false,\"type\":\"float\"},\"productId\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},
    \"partNumber\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"name\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"metaKeywords\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"metaDescription\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"metaTitle\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"shortDescription\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"fullDescription\":{\"type\":\"text\"}}}}\r\n# Response:\r\n{\"statusCode\":404,\"error\":\"Not Found\",\"message\":\"Not Found\"}\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED..!!!

this post helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/62987881/9810921

This is the working code

```
var pool = new CloudConnectionPool(
    "<cloud id retrieved from the Elastic Cloud web console>", 
    new BasicAuthenticationCredentials(config.Username, config.Password));
    
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

This is how we can get could id https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-create-deployment.html